# Using Mean Value Theorem to solve an inequality involving $\cos^{-1}(x)$

Tags: real-analysis

> **Question:**
>
> Using the Mean Value Theorem, show that for all $-\frac{1}{2}\lt a,b \lt \frac{1}{2}$ with $a\lt b$
>
> $$\lvert \cos^{-1}(a)-\cos^{-1}(b)\rvert \lt \frac{2\sqrt{3}}{3}\lvert a-b\rvert$$

**My attempt:**

Let $f(x)= \cos^{-1}(x)$

$\cos^{-1}(x)\ \text{is continuous and differentiable on the interval so by the MVT,} $

$$\lvert \cos^{-1}(b)-\cos^{-1}(a) \rvert= \lvert b-a\rvert.\lvert f'(c)\rvert$$

$$\lvert f'(c) \rvert= \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-c^2}} \lt \frac{2\sqrt{3}}{3} $$

Therefore we have,

$$\lvert \cos^{-1}(a)-\cos^{-1}(b) \rvert= \lvert a-b\rvert.\lvert f'(c) \rvert \le 1.\lvert a-b\rvert \lt \lvert b-a\rvert \frac{2\sqrt{3}}{3}$$

Because $\lvert a-b\rvert= \lvert b -a\rvert$

Would this be correct?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

$|f'(c)| = \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{1 - c^2}} < \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{1 - (1/2)^2}}$ since $c^2 < (1/2)^2$.

Comment: But c can equal 0 can it not?

Comment: Yes, yet $c$ could be $1/4$, in which case $|f'(1/4)| = \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{1 - (1/4)^2}} = \dfrac{4}{\sqrt{15}} > 1$.

Comment: I see! Thanks for that

Comment: So how would I conclude the final answer? Could I simply have $\frac{4}{\sqrt{15}} \lt \frac{2\sqrt{3}}{3}$

Comment: Not quite like that. Instead, we know that $-1/2 < c < 1/2$, so $c^2 < 1/4$. Therefore $1 - c^2 > 3/4$ or rather $\sqrt{1 - c^2} > \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}$. Then we see that $\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{1 - c^2}} < \frac{2}{\sqrt{3}}$ as desired.

Comment: I see, thank you for your help steven!

Answer (score 1):

No, this wouldn't be correct. The equality you wrote from the MVT is not right; if you take absolute values, then you must also have $|f'(c)|$ in the RHS; and just because $f'(c) < 1$ it doesn't mean its absolute value is also $<1$.

Comment: I have now edited it

Comment: You still don't have $|f'(c)|$ in the RHS right at the top, so even if the rest is correct, this step breaks the whole proof. Also, what's tan(a) and tan(b) doing there? What's tan got to do with anything?

Comment: I have just changed that, possibly refresh the page?

Comment: Is it now correct?

Comment: Not yet. $c^2$ can be as high as $1/4$, so $\dfrac 1 {\sqrt{1-c^2}}$ could be as high as $\dfrac {2\sqrt 3} 3$, where did $\sqrt{15}$ come from?